# Angular 10 custom directive file is not triggering on component loads

Tags: angular, typescript, custom-directive

In my angular project, I have a custom directive to hide and show the button. I created the directive file and then imported the directive into the shared module.ts file. Components are also available in the shared module only. but on component load directive not loading and not even triggering. but it looks everything fine only. I couldn't able to find out the reason for this issue.

I imported sharedmodule.ts in app.module.ts and in console also there is not errors, components also rendering properly, but directive is not triggering.

Can you help me to fix this.

Directive File:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { UserContextService } from '../../services/usercontext/user-context.service';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Directive({ selector: '[Customacl]' })
export class DataCustomaclDirective {
   constructor(private template: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private userContext: UserContextService) { }

@Input()
set DataCustomacl(role: string) {
    debugger
    if (role) this.viewContainer.clear();
    else this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
}
}
```

Component.html:

```
<button type="button" Customacl >Submit</button>
```

Shared.module.ts:

```
import { DataCustomaclDirective } from './directives/acl';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SearchName } from './servicer.name.pipe';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [DataCustomaclDirective, ],
    providers: [SearchName],
    exports: [DataCustomaclDirective]
})

export class SharedModule {
   static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<SharedModule> {
       return {
        ngModule: SharedModule,
        providers: [AlertService]
      };
   }
}
```

Comment: So, did you import the SharedModule?

Comment: @helloworld yes, in app.module.ts i imported..

Answer (score 1):

I created a reproduce version of your code [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r7aunu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

First of all, to do the logic as you want, your directive should be a structural directive that is use with the *, eg: `*Customacl`.

Its will throw error like `Error: NG0201: No provider for TemplateRef found. ...`

Secondly, the setter `DataCustomacl` will not trigger because you did not pass any data into your directive (you can check in the stackblitz code)

Comment: I guess as you said I missed the pass any data to directive. thank you for your proper explanations.